# Regarding the formal proof of De Morgan's law.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Refering to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Part_1, in the formal proof of De Morgan's Law, it was stated that

> Let $x \in (A\cap B)^c$ then $x \notin (A\cap B)$. 
> Because $A\cap B=\{y \mid y \in A \text { and } y\in B\}$, it must be the case that $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$.

What I can't comprehend is that they're saying that if $x$ is not common to both $A$ and $B$ , then $x$ doesn't belong in $A$ or in $B$. How is that possible.

For example if I were to say that $A=\{1,2,3,4,7,9\}$ and $B=\{7,8,9,11\}$ and say $x=3$. So $A\cap B = \{7,9\}$. Clearly $x=3\notin A\cap B$. But in this case $x$ does belong to the set $A$.

Doesn't that contradict the statement given in the proof.

Comment: EITHER $x \notin A$ or $x\notin B$. It is not necessary that both hold. For example, we see that $3 \notin B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A, B$ be sets. The *De Morgan’s Law* says that $x \notin A \cap B$ if and only if $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B.$

In your case, note that $3 \in A$ and $3 \notin B,$ so the disjunction “$3 \notin A$ or $3 \notin B$” is true, because at least one of these conditions is true, namely that $3 \notin B.$

By the *De Morgan’s Law* we have that $3 \notin A \cap B$ which we can easily verify that is true.

Also, note that what the *De Morgan’s Law* is telling us is that some objects are not elements of both sets if and only if those objects does not belong to at least on of those sets. This makes sense intuitively.

In the most basic way, these definitions are all constructed applying the mathematical definition of *and* and *or* (which in logic are related to the *conjunction* $\wedge$ and *disjunction* $\vee$ of statements).