# Clarification regarding proof of De Morgan's theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

One of DeMorgan's law states that $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$.

To prove $(A \cap B)^c \subseteq A^c \cup B^c$

I am following the proof given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Part_1

Let $(A \cap B)^c$. Then $x \notin A \cap B$. Because $A \wedge B = \{y | y \in  A \vee y \in B\}$,
it must be the case that $x \notin  A$ *or* $x \notin  B$.

Can you explain why $x \notin  A$ **or** $x \notin  B$ is followed from $A \wedge B = \{y | y \in  A \vee y \in B\}$

This insertion of ***or*** is not understood.

Close question : [Regarding the formal proof of De Morgan's law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844798/regarding-the-formal-proof-of-de-morgans-law)

Comment: If $x$ is not in both $A$ and $B$, then it must be true that either: $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, or $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$, or $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$, which concisely put is $x \in A^c$ 'or' $x \in B^c$

Comment: @Snoop  Quote  {x∈A and x∉B, or x∉A and x∈B, or x∉A and x∉B, which concisely put is x∈Ac 'or' x∈Bc}. Can you elaborate or prove why it can be ' concisely put '.

Comment: Wrong: Then $x ∉ A \cap B$. Because $A \cap B = \{ y | y∈A \land y∈B \}$ ...Thus, to say that $x$ is **not** in $A \cap B$ means that $x$ does **not** satisfy the condition defining $A \cap B$, i.e. it is not true that: $x∈A \text { and } x∈B$.